# Dropbox Installation

Tags: xubuntu, software-installation, dropbox

I am trying to install Dropbox to my Xubuntu 14.04 and I found two ways to do this from their official site and I am just wondering which one is the best.

Option -1 :
https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Option -2 :
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/dropbox?dist=trusty

I tried to follow the option 2 method but the command line result is the following

`X@Y:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.8QwEMoXWMR --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/chromium-daily-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/deluge-team-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/hydr0g3n-qbittorrent-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/otto-kesselgulasch-gimp.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pidgin-developers-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/videolan-stable-daily.gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
gpg: requesting key 5044912E from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
gpgkeys: key 5044912E can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0`

So nothing just happened here and i didn't go further with Option 2.

Comment: Did you try the first?

Comment: Try downloading it from the ubuntu software centre

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the response. I went along with the option 1.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue at office.
Simply add hkp:// to the keyserver address and add port 80 like this :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 5044912E
```

It should work ;)

Comment: Add **-E** parameter in sudo to works even behind a proxy: `sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 5044912E`

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem on Ubuntu 16.06. I ignored it, went ahead and added "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ xenial main" to my sources.list and dropbox installed fine.